# Can't change baud rate of ttyUSB0 in Ubuntu 18.04 (galiumos)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port

I wasn't able to use an app with the diagnostic interface until I changed ttyUSB0 baud rate to 9600 with the command :

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

and after restarting app it wasn't working again because baud rate switched again to 0.
So my question is how to set baud rate permanently to 9600 so my app can work.

Answer (score 0):

> after restarting app it wasn't working again because baud rate switched again to 0.

This implies that either your application, or the driver are reverting the configuration on close.

> So my question is how to set baud rate permanently to 9600 so my app can work

You can't. Linux doesn't have a "*default configuration*" that you can set up like Windows does... and even Windows' "*default configuration*" is flawed when it comes to hotplugging USB adapters.

Ideally your application will set up the serial port correctly when it opens it (you have no idea what state it was left in, so you'll want to assert your required configuration). How you do this will depend on the language you're using, but a simple `open(2)` will not be enough... there are many tutorials and libraries to support you doing this for all languages I can think of.

Less ideally, you can run `stty` each time before your application starts, which appears to be what you're doing already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
It turned out that when I turned off the program, the device disconnect itself and then immediately connect.
In my case, writing 'udev rule' helped. Now whenever this device connects, the baud rate is set to 9600.

Comment: Ah, well done - a udev rule isn't a bad idea... I would still advise against it in favour of "doing it properly" though.